# adding object array with nodejs and read it on file.txt

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

lets say i have these objects

```
{name:'somename',date:'10/20'}
{name:'anothername',date:'07/30'}
```

in my file using node i can read these objects
and i want these to to be an array so i used `.split('\n')`
 the problem is i get it as a string means if i try to

```
objectArray.map((singleObject)=>{
console.log(singleObject.name)
})
```

i got `undefined`

thats how i write the objects on my file.txt

```
fs.appendFile(path.join(__dirname,'file.txt'),
        object,(e)=>{
            console.log(e);
    })
```

Comment: can you post what do you have in objectArray

Comment: it does not seem to be a valid array

Comment: const objectArray=objects.split('\n') //objects is what comes out from file.txt

Comment: ok can you post what do you get console.log(JSON.stringify(singleObject));

Comment: {"text":"bat","movie":"waleed","name":"Guest"}

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at Object.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: try this console.log(singleObject["name"])

Comment: it actually works i dont understand why

Comment: You can access property using dot and [] notation

Comment: Mark if that helped

Comment: actually i found my problem was that i don't use JSON.parse(singleObject)

Comment: I asked you earlier

Comment: Can you mark the answer

Answer (score 2):

JSON string should be in '{"key":"value"}' format

so you should write it in required format.

```
fs.appendFile(path.join(__dirname,'file.txt'),
    JSON.stringify(object),(e)=>{
        console.log(e);
});
```

after read file, parse data.

```
fs.readFile('file.txt','utf8',function(err,data){
   data = data.split("\n");
   var a = JSON.parse(data[0]);
   console.log(a);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing as follows

```
console.log(singleObject["name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

By splitting your file using `\n`, you have a valid and iterable array, but what you may need to considered about is that each entry of `objectArray` is a string, not an object! So you need to make it an object, by using `JSON.parse`, before you access its properties. Thus your final code will be as follows.

```
objectArray.map((singleObject) => {
    let obj = JSON.parse(singleObject)
    console.log(obj.name)
})
```